# Thermodynamics of borax dissolution

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solubility

I'm currently experimenting with the dissolution of borax $\ce{Na2B4O7.10H2O}$. The procedure was quite simple, samples of saturated borax at different temperatures are titrated, then the value of $\ce{K_{sp}}$ can be determined. From different values of $\ce{lnK_{sp}}$ and $\ce{ln{1/T}}$, some thermodynamics parameters such as $\Delta H$, $\Delta S$  can be found.

However, the main problem is that the solubility of borax we found by titration is extremely low compared to the information we can find on the Internet. We suspect the source of error lies in the preparation of a saturated borax solution. So, my question is, ***How can we prepare such a saturated solution at different temperatures?***

Here are some of my observations after doing this experiment over and over:

- We looked up the solubility of borax (about 30g/100 mL of water at $\ce{60^{o}C}$), so we weighed 30g of borax and put it in 100mL of water and heat it to $\ce{60^{o}C}$. However, according to my observations, there is still a lot of undissolved borax. Does It mean that this is way too wrong? Like, should I do another method that I've read that I should put the solute in gradually and when all of them dissolved, just add a little more until they are no longer soluble? Did I make a supersaturated solution or something like that?
- Some prelab guides I found on the Internet say that I should continuously stir while gently heating the solution. I tried but it didn't help at all. The substance that should be crystallized at the bottom of the container is now dispersed throughout the solution, which is a potential source of error.
- Some say I should let the solution at much rest as possible for about 10 min to ensure that equilibrium is reached. With all equipment that I have, I can just let it rest in the hot bath that was used for heating. However, what if the temperature rises over the point that borax got dehydrated (just a little bit over $\ce{60^{o}C}$) or decreases more quickly by interacting with the surrounding? I tried but this seems too hard.
- Finally, my idea for changing the temperature of the solution is to let that solution at $\ce{60^{o}C}$ cool down gradually. Several editions of lab reports I found on the Internet show that I should prepare, like, 5 solutions for 5 different temperatures. And also, is it true that using ice can make the temperature change so quickly that the equilibrium between borax (solid) and borax (dissolved in the solution) cannot be established? So if I cannot use ice, how can I prepare a saturated solution of borax at some low temperatures like $\ce{20^{o}C}$?

I've tried several times and the results are still quite bad. Hope I can find reasons for it. Thanks for reading such a looong question of mine and I would be really really appreciate your help.

Comment: In the 2nd paragraph you state that the solubility of borax is **extremely low** compared to the data found in Internet. Extremely low ? In the 3rd paragraph, the theoretical solubility of borax at 60°C is 30 g/100 mL water. In the Handbook of  Chemistry and Physics, the solubility of borax is 14.2 g/100 mL at 55°C, and 201 g/100 mL at 100°C. Its solubility shows a huge variation between 50°C and 100°C. It is 15 times more soluble at 100°C than at 55°C.  Maybe your temperature is not the same in all parts of your solutions ? This may explain your results.

Comment: Some substances dissolve *slowly*, so giving sufficient time may be an issue. Also, the directions to produce a truly *saturated* solution at 60°C would *expect* some undissolved solids at bottom -- the solution *above* is saturated, and can be separated by decantation or filtering.